# Appendix labels in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I am using the `book` class and have several appendices. These are titled 'Appendix A', 'Appendix B', etc., where actually all letters are small caps. To achieve small caps for the labels (A, B, ...), I use `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\normalfont\scshape \alph{chapter}}}`. While that works fine, it also changes the appendix labels in the table of contents to small caps, which I don't want. I can't figure out how to avoid this. Does anyone know of a package, or a trick, that would make the labels A, B, etc., appear as normal capitals in the toc?

The following reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,twoside,dvipsnames]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[top=1.2in,bottom=1.15in,right=1.15in,left=1.15in,headheight=50pt,headsep=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=.753]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes,nolessnomore]{mathastext}
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+calt,+clig,+dlig,liga,cv06}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\, #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{50pt} % make space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {\filcenter\normalfont\romanspaced\large\scshape chapter\ \thechapter}
    {.2cm}
    {\normalfont\Large\romanspaced\itshape\filcenter}
    
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\itshape\filcenter}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\author{\Large Author}
\date{}

\frontmatter

\title{\Huge \textsc{title} \\[5cm] {}}

\maketitle

\begingroup
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={NoContextual}}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[
  Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced},
]
\fancyhead[C]{\emph{Contents}}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Preface}

\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}

Some text here ...

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{\rightmark}}

\chapter{Introduction}

Some more text ...

\chapter{Second chapter}

... and more ...

\appendix

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\textsc{\alph{chapter}}}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {\filcenter\normalfont\romanspaced\large\scshape appendix \thechapter}
    {.2cm}
    {\normalfont\Large\romanspaced\itshape\filcenter}

\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Proof of Theorem 1}

... still more text ...

\chapter{Proof of Theorem 2}

... and more ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try with  `\textsc{\alph{chapter}}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Very strange… Could you post a small, yet complete code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I have edited the question, adding a MWE (though not so minimal -- sorry, this was the best I could do).

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient solution for your example would be to redefine \textsc just before \tableofcontents (while ensuring that the whole is grouped, so the redefinition remains local):

```
{\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\MakeUppercase #1}
\tableofcontents
}
```

Something more refined would be called for in cases where small caps are needed somewhere in the toc.

Comment: This solved the problem -- thanks!